# python pandas dataframe equivalent function logic for nonzero value calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, pine-script

This is a pinescript code which I am trying to code in python.what shall be an optimized equivalent python code be for the same

kama[1] here is previous kama value, for first-time calc in an array what should be done for this kama[1] value as it would not exist the first time.

```
 kama=nz(kama[1], close[1])+smooth*(close[1]-nz(kama[1], close[1]))
```

pinescript info :

```
nz
Replaces NaN values with zeros (or given value) in a series.
nz(x, y) → integer

nz(sma(close, 100))
RETURNS
Two args version: returns x if it's a valid (not NaN) number, otherwise y
One arg version: returns x if it's a valid (not NaN) number, otherwise 0
ARGUMENTS
x (series) Series of values to process.
y (float) Value that will be inserted instead of all NaN values in x series.
```

**edit 1**
something i tried as below that is not working

```
stockdata['kama'] = stockdata['kama'](-1) if stockdata['kama'](-1) !=0 \
 else stockdata['close'] + stockdata['smooth']*(stockdata['close'] - \
 stockdata['kama'](-1) if stockdata['kama'](-1) !=0 else stockdata['close'])
```

**edit 2**
the alternative i tried just to make sure at least one part is working but that is also failing (nz(kama[1], close))

```
stockdata['kama'] = np.where(stockdata['kama'][-1] != 0, stockdata['kama'][-1], stockdata['close'])
```

completely struck now if this line of

```
 kama=nz(kama[1], close)+smooth*(close-nz(kama[1], close))
```

pine-script code not converted to python my whole logic will go for a toss. any of your working solutions are greatly appreciated.

**edit 3:**
the dataframe input of the series

```
                 open       high        low      close  adjusted_close  \
date                                                                     
2002-07-01     5.2397     5.5409     5.2397     5.4127          0.0634   
2002-07-02     5.5234     5.5370     5.4214     5.4438          0.0638   
2002-07-03     5.5060     5.5458     5.3281     5.4661          0.0640   
2002-07-04     5.5011     5.5720     5.4175     5.5283          0.0647   
2002-07-05     5.5633     5.6566     5.4749     5.5905          0.0655   
2002-07-08     5.5011     5.7187     5.5011     5.6255          0.0659   
2002-07-09     5.5905     5.7586     5.5681     5.6167          0.0658   
2002-07-10     5.4885     5.4885     5.1465     5.2222          0.0612   
2002-07-11     4.9784     5.2135     4.9784     5.1863          0.0607   
2002-07-12     5.5011     5.5011     5.2446     5.3194          0.0623   
2002-07-15     5.3243     5.4797     5.1912     5.3330          0.0625   
2002-07-16     5.1999     5.4389     5.1999     5.3155          0.0623   
2002-07-17     4.7024     5.1377     4.6189     5.0445          0.0591   
2002-07-18     4.8803     5.1465     4.8356     5.0804          0.0595   
2002-07-19     5.0270     5.2038     5.0221     5.1513          0.0603   
2002-07-22     5.0804     5.1465     4.9687     4.9735          0.0582   
2002-07-23     4.8181     5.0843     4.8181     5.0619          0.0593   
2002-07-24     5.0580     5.1290     4.9376     5.0619          0.0593   
2002-07-25     5.0580     5.0580     4.7918     4.8492          0.0568

             volume  dividend_amount  split_coefficient           Om  \
date                                                                   
2002-07-01    21923              0.0                1.0          NaN   
2002-07-02    61045              0.0                1.0          NaN   
2002-07-03    34161              0.0                1.0          NaN   
2002-07-04    27893              0.0                1.0          NaN   
2002-07-05    58976              0.0                1.0          NaN   
2002-07-08    48910              0.0                1.0     5.472433   
2002-07-09   321846              0.0                1.0     5.530900   
2002-07-10   138434              0.0                1.0     5.525083   
2002-07-11    15027              0.0                1.0     5.437150   
2002-07-12    24187              0.0                1.0     5.437150   
2002-07-15    50330              0.0                1.0     5.397317   
2002-07-16    24928              0.0                1.0     5.347117   
2002-07-17    21357              0.0                1.0     5.199100   
2002-07-18    27532              0.0                1.0     5.097733   
2002-07-19    13380              0.0                1.0     5.105833   
2002-07-22    21666              0.0                1.0     5.035717   
2002-07-23    40161              0.0                1.0     4.951350   
2002-07-24    34480              0.0                1.0     4.927700   
2002-07-25    38185              0.0                1.0     4.986967  

                     Hm           Lm           Cm       vClose       diff  \
date                                                                        
2002-07-01          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  1669.8373   
2002-07-02          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  1669.8062   
2002-07-03          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  1669.7839   
2002-07-04          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  1669.7217   
2002-07-05          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN  1669.6595   
2002-07-08     5.595167     5.397117     5.511150     5.493967  1669.6245   
2002-07-09     5.631450     5.451850     5.545150     5.539837  1669.6333   
2002-07-10     5.623367     5.406033     5.508217     5.515675  1670.0278   
2002-07-11     5.567983     5.347750     5.461583     5.453617  1670.0637   
2002-07-12     5.556167     5.318933     5.426767     5.434754  1669.9306   
2002-07-15     5.526683     5.271650     5.383850     5.394875  1669.9170   
2002-07-16     5.480050     5.221450     5.332183     5.345200  1669.9345   
2002-07-17     5.376567     5.063250     5.236817     5.218933  1670.2055   
2002-07-18     5.319567     5.011433     5.213183     5.160479  1670.1696   
2002-07-19     5.317950     5.018717     5.207350     5.162463  1670.0987   
2002-07-22     5.258850     4.972733     5.149700     5.104250  1670.2765   
2002-07-23     5.192950     4.910550     5.104517     5.039842  1670.1881   
2002-07-24     5.141300     4.866833     5.062250     4.999521  1670.1881   
2002-07-25     5.128017     4.895650     5.029700     5.010083  1670.4008

               signal      noise      efratio       smooth  
date                                                        
2002-07-01     5.4127  1670.3373     0.003240     0.416113  
2002-07-02     5.4438  1670.3062     0.003259     0.416113  
2002-07-03     5.4661  1670.2839     0.003273     0.416114  
2002-07-04     5.5283  1670.2217     0.003310     0.416115  
2002-07-05     5.5905  1670.1595     0.003347     0.416116  
2002-07-08     5.6255  1670.1245     0.003368     0.416116  
2002-07-09     5.6167  1670.1333     0.003363     0.416116  
2002-07-10     5.2222  1670.5278     0.003126     0.416110  
2002-07-11     5.1863  1670.5637     0.003105     0.416109  
2002-07-12     5.3194  1670.4306     0.003184     0.416111  
2002-07-15     5.3330  1670.4170     0.003193     0.416111  
2002-07-16     5.3155  1670.4345     0.003182     0.416111  
2002-07-17     5.0445  1670.7055     0.003019     0.416107  
2002-07-18     5.0804  1670.6696     0.003041     0.416107  
2002-07-19     5.1513  1670.5987     0.003084     0.416109  
2002-07-22     4.9735  1670.7765     0.002977     0.416106  
2002-07-23     5.0619  1670.6881     0.003030     0.416107  
2002-07-24     5.0619  1670.6881     0.003030     0.416107  
2002-07-25     4.8492  1670.9008     0.002902     0.416104
```

what is expected for  kama=nz(kama[1], close)+smooth*(close-nz(kama[1], close))?

```
stockdata['kama'] =nz(stockdata[kama][-1],stockdata['close'] +stockdata['smooth']*(stockdata['close']-nz(stockdata['kama'][-1],stockdata['close'])
```

in this case for first iteration there will not be any previous kama value which should be taken care. all the inputs are given in dataframe format above.

Comment: Hi Mike ,Any solution for this ,this code not working the same crash here as well

Comment: And I forget, better is create new question. So remove all columns from sample data, give only `close` and `smooth` (and maybe `kama`) and add expected output. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the column `kama` first with the values of `close`:

```
import numpy as np

stockdata['kama'] = stockdata['close']
previous_kama = stockdata['kama'].shift()
previous_close = stockdata['close'].shift()
value = np.where(previous_kama.notnull(), previous_kama, previous_close)
stockdata['kama'] = value  + stockdata['smooth'] * (previous_close - value)
```

Comment: instead of keeping single variable as value , for this desired function kama=nz(kama[1], close)+smooth*(close-nz(kama[1], close))  i want the output as given in the edit 1 section where stockdata['kama'] should be equal to kama=nz(kama[1], close)+smooth*(close-nz(kama[1], close)) in dataframe format here close is stockdata['close'] in dataframe format.

Comment: `value` is just a temporary helper.

Comment: the above code in the first line itself crashes "previous_kama = stockdata['kama'].shift()". need the stockdata dataframe format output for kama for this function kama=nz(kama[1], close)+smooth*(close-nz(kama[1], close))

Comment: Muller need some working solution, the above your logic also failed, can any other alternate method you have?

Comment: You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Give inputs and desired outputs. I cannot fix "the above logic failed".  You have to be way more specific and provide a clear example I can actually reproduce.

Comment: The details are given in the edit3. Hope this helps.Let me know if any more details required.

Comment: Need the solution ,as my complete development in struck at this now.

Comment: Muller ,Any solution to this.

Comment: Desired result can only be seen from this function as the original code not giving any option to plot this kama alone. i have a quess of the problem is that for the first row kama calculation the prvious kama is cheked whics is Nan in this case  logic will break so the previous kama is replaced with current row close (only for the first row). This is what the logic does ..

Comment: Dear Kai ,A fundamental problem is seen and corrected in the original input itself where the logic relies on the previous close value wherever you would see [1] this means previous value. Can you please post a code for this logic.Please note that for the first iteration alone kama will be replaced with close there after a previous kama has to be used in logical calculation.I hope now i will get the right code.

Comment: Just use the `close` from the step before. Updated my answer.

Comment: Dear Kai, With this code, the crash is gone.Thanks a ton to you.I hope i can finish the logic now.

Comment: can this be made as wrapper function or is there any oneline function that can do non zero operation .Now i have many function that deals with non zero and need some support for the same.

Comment: is there any NZ equivalent function in python